# Powershell crash when launching

Tags: powershell

Whenever I run powershell.exe or scripts via powershell_ise.exe its crash.
I wanted to see the exception of this crash and I found out it is because of type conversion.
I cannot understand why it is even making a type conversion when starting it.
Can someone please help me.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Well, you have to post the code first so we can help you :)

Comment: Try `powershell -NoProfile`. If this works then you have a script loading at PowerShell startup that has a problem. Review this for locations where startup script files are stored: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: It is not that I am running a code, the only thing I do is to run powershell.exe.
I tried to do powershell -NoProfile, but I still receiving this error.